# Theory of Numbers (questions)

Tags: number-theory

If *m* is a prime number and *a,b* are two numbers less than *m*. Prove that

$a^{m-2}+a^{m-3}b+a^{m-4}b^2+......+b^{m-2}$

is a multiple of *m*.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be true: Take $m=3$, $a=b=2$. The expression is essentially $(2+2)^1=4$ which is not a multiple of 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given number times $a-b$ is $a^{m-1}-b^{m-1}$.  By [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem), we have $$a^{m-1}-b^{m-1}\equiv 1-1=0\pmod{m}$$

Provided $a\neq b$, since $m$ divides the given number times $a-b$, and does not divide $a-b$, we must have that $m$ divides the given number.

On the other hand, if $a=b$, then the sum is exactly $a^{m-2}(m-1)$, which is in general not a multiple of $m$.  Hence we need $a\neq b$ for the statement to be true.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: multiply your sum with $a-b$ to get $a^{m-1}-b^{m-1}$. Then use little Fermat Theorem.